# Alert pop up message when I click on submit

Tags: php

I am modifying a code for a small WebERP application.

```
echo '<td>
            <input type="hidden" name="CradTYPE'.$profInd.'" value="' . $row['cardType'] . '" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ProfileID'.$profInd.'" value="' . $row['profileId'] . '" />
            <input type="hidden" name="LastFour'.$profInd.'" value="' . $row['accountNo'] . '" />
            <input type="submit" name="SubmitID'.$profInd.'" value="Process" />
        </td>';
```

When I click on Proceed. The database gets updated with the default code. Before it gets updated, I want it to have a pop message reading. 'Which date do you want to choose?'. With two options A. today's days B. Journal date. How can I do that on the above PHP code?

Comment: You can't do that using just php, but you also need client side scripts. Anyways, try searching on Google and try some codes. Later if you have any problems with the code, then post your queries. This is not a do my homework website :(

Comment: I meant, you can find your required code by a simple google search. The above code has no approach or trial to attain your requirement. So you are just asking us to write the codes for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Show some of the code.. Alert is basically not possible until you use some JavaScript along with html.. Or you can redirect user to another page to ask for the options.. If you don't want to use javascript.

Comment: Thats not an answer, thats a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You would need Javascript for that. Try looking at the prompt() function. You can then implement two select for the dates on the window that popups.

Comment: Thats not an answer, thats a comment. Anyways, the OP is not looking for a simple alert, but for a modal or popup box with multiple choices.